# AWS Lambda Python Boto3 client.invoke() times out no matter what parameters are entered

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am attempting to call one lambda function from another, and the code I am using in the calling function is:

```
client=boto3.client('lambda')
services={'Image_Processor':'arn'}
response=client.invoke(FunctionName=services[event['service']], InvocationType='DryRun', Payload=json.dumps(event))
```

There is no error message given, and I have tried setting the timeout duration as long as 10 minutes, but I still cannot get any result except:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2021-08-12T17:13:18.946Z de2feefa-9923-40bd-a555-bf5de54712ee Task timed out after 20.02 seconds"
}
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function (that is timing out) connected to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason _why_ it is connected to a VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are saying that *Lambda function A* is timing out when invoking *Lambda function B*.

A common scenario is that the timeout is **caused by Lambda function A not having access to the Internet**. The AWS API endpoint is on the Internet and Lambda function A requires Internet access to invoke Lambda function B.

To have Internet access, the Lambda function should either:

- *NOT* be connected to a VPC (which then automatically provides Internet access), *or*
- Be connected to a private subnet, and the VPC should have an Internet Gateway in a public subnet to grant access to the Internet, *or*
- [Configure interface VPC endpoints for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc-endpoints.html), which creates a direct connection between a VPC and the AWS Lambda API endpoint

Comment: They are in a VPC and I haven't configured an endpoint, but the calling function is able to successfully make SQL calls to a table I set up using Aurora, which implies internet access doesn't it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have chosen to connect the AWS Lambda function to the VPC?

Comment: Not particularly; aren't there heightened security risks not putting the functions in a VPC?

Comment: You should _not_ connect the AWS Lambda function to the VPC. It will then automatically have Internet access and it will be able to communicate with both Amazon Aurora and Amazon Lambda. There are no in-bound capabilities to such a configuration, so it is just as safe as putting it in a VPC. The best default choice is _not_ to put a Lambda function a VPC unless there is a reason to do so.

Comment: Alright thanks for the tip. I'll try that out now then.

Comment: Actually, is it possible for me to leave the child function in the VPC and still have it called by the parent? It requires access to an EFS which caused an error when I just tried to remove it from the VPC

Comment: Yes. The second function can remain connected to the VPC (since it has a reason!), and it can be invoked by the first function from 'outside' the VPC (because the AWS Lambda API endpoint is outside the VPC). The Lambda service will invoke the function regardless of how/where it is connected.

Comment: Alright I got it working! Thanks for all the help